# How to find $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.5^i \cdot i^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know how to solve how to find $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.5^i \cdot i$ using

$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.5^i \cdot i = 0.5 + 0.5^2*2 + 0.5^3*3 + 0.5^4*4 + \ldots \\
    = (0.5 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + 0.5^4 + \ldots) + (0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + \ldots ) + (0.5^3 + \ldots ) + \ldots \\
    = 1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + \ldots = 2
$$

I'm trying to apply the analogous approach for $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.5^i \cdot i^2$?
I end up with something that looks like
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 0.5^i\cdot i^2 = 
    = 0.5 + 0.5^2*2^2 + 0.5^3*3^2 + 0.5^4*4^2 + \ldots \\
    = (0.5 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + 0.5^4 + \ldots) + 3(0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + \ldots ) + 5(0.5^3 + \ldots ) + \ldots \\
    = 1 + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 5\cdot \frac{1}{4} + 7 \cdot \frac{1}{8} + 9 \cdot \frac{1}{16} + \ldots  \\
    = (1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 + \ldots) + 2(0.5 + 0.125 + \ldots ) + 2*(0.25 + 0.125 + \ldots) + 2*(0.125 + \ldots) \\
    = 2 + 2 * 1 + 2 * 0.5 + 2 * 0.25 + 2 * 0.125 + \ldots 
    = 2 + 2(1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + \ldots) \\
    = 6
$$

This was a bit convoluted and I was wondering if there's a simpler way to arrive at this after having the result for $\sum 0.5^i \cdot i$?

Comment: Starting with $f(x)=\sum x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$ compute the deriviatives of $f(x)$ and adjust the powers of $x$ that appear.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm